# How to get actionBar size properly programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I need to shift a `RecyclerView` down by the size of my `actionBar` when a `Button` click occurs.

I tried this code

```
  params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) myrv.getLayoutParams();

  public void changeRecyclerViewPosition() {
    params.setMargins(0, android.R.attr.actionBarSize, 0, 0);
    myrv.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

And as a result the `RecyclerView` disapears when the `Button` is clicked.

So I tried to log the `android.R.attr.actionBarSize` value and it's too big (2130903043).

I thought that maybe the result is in `pixels` and it needs to be converted to dp.

So can you guys explain to me what's wrong and the reason behind that behaviour ?

EDIT:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
tools:context=".Activities.LoadSavedCoffretDataActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cancel_img"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete_img"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_black_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout

Comment: See EDIT please.

Comment: show the code of button click

Comment: @ManojPerumarath The action is happening in the adapter. Because when I perform a long click in any Recycler View item, checkboxes appears and I need to shift Recycler View position down by the value of the Action bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Action bar height by

```
public void changeRecyclerViewPosition() {
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
int actionBarHeight = 0;
if (getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
params.setMargins(0,actionBarHeight, 0, 0);
myrv.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but nothing is happening.

Comment: Just toast the value it will show the exact height, I don't know the rest of your code so it can't give you a complete solution

Comment: It's actually working , thank you again Sir . I multiplied `actionBarHeight` by 2 , in my xml layout the recycler view top margin is already the action bar height, so when I change that margin programatically , the recycler view margin is reset to 0 . So i needed to add the `actionBarHeight` to the actual margin. I hope I delivered my point clearly.

Comment: Ok buddy, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml for fixed App Bar Size 
the main line is

```
**android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"**

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my point brother. I need to change the margin of the recyclerView by the height of my actionBar .

Comment: post your layout @Amine

Comment: Please take a look at EDIT Sir.

Comment: Does it means you need to make Recycler View as of Action Bar on Button Click

Comment: No I need to change the Recycler View position down by a value of the Action Bar height